# I got error related with jquery when installing summernote in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3, summernote

i have some problem with jquery, i dont know what to do

i have following the instruction in https://summernote.org/getting-started/

i have insert this code in head tag

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script> 
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.12/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.12/summernote.js"></script>
```

then set the textarea id to summernote

```
    <div class="form-group col-md-8">
      <label>Content</label>
        <textarea id="summernote" style="height: 200px;" name="isi_informasi"><?= $konten ?></textarea>
    </div>
```

and insert this function code in end of body tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#summernote').summernote();
   });
</script>
```

i got this error massage in console

```
jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).summernote is not a function TypeError: $(...).summernote is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (http://localhost/okifftuh/admin/createInformation/2:533:30)
    at mightThrow (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js:3583:29)
    at process (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js:3651:12) undefined

jQuery.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery.js:3860
process @ jquery.js:3655
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery.js:3689
fire @ jquery.js:3317
fireWith @ jquery.js:3447
fire @ jquery.js:3455
fire @ jquery.js:3317
fireWith @ jquery.js:3447
ready @ jquery.js:3920
completed @ jquery.js:3930
```

=======================================================================

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).summernote is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (2:533)
    at mightThrow (jquery.js:3583)
    at process (jquery.js:3651)

(anonymous) @ 2:533
mightThrow @ jquery.js:3583
process @ jquery.js:3651
setTimeout (async)
jQuery.readyException @ jquery.js:3868
(anonymous) @ jquery.js:3888
mightThrow @ jquery.js:3583
process @ jquery.js:3651
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery.js:3689
fire @ jquery.js:3317
fireWith @ jquery.js:3447
fire @ jquery.js:3455
fire @ jquery.js:3317
fireWith @ jquery.js:3447
process @ jquery.js:3671
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ jquery.js:3689
fire @ jquery.js:3317
fireWith @ jquery.js:3447
fire @ jquery.js:3455
fire @ jquery.js:3317
fireWith @ jquery.js:3447
ready @ jquery.js:3920
completed @ jquery.js:3930
```

Comment: I'm Not getting the same code in Ques....its working fine.....Its might be related to multiple JS loading......Can you provide your page html code...

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a summernote versioning compatibility issue with jquery, try using `JQuery 3.2.0` and `Summernote 0.8.2` version respectively :

```
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.js"></script> 
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script> 
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.2/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.2/summernote.js" defer></script>
```

More detailed compatibility issue list is [here](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/2087#issuecomment-318735583).